# Is there a multi account container feature on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, containers

I have to use the feature multi account containers on the firefox browser to access a certain URL. Is there a way to use the same feature on chrome?

I couldn't find this feature, hopefully someone knows how to find it.
I found an answer stating that Edge does not allow it but myabe there is a way to do it on Chrome that I just can't see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for 2023, there's NO equivalent of FF's multi-containers in Brave/Chrome.
https://superuser.com/questions/1549798/is-there-a-chrome-equivalent-for-firefoxs-multi-account-container-extension